# Adverb meaning "to where"?

Tags: adverbs

"whence" means "from where" or "from which". Does English have an analogous meaning "to where?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Whither" means "to where".

[Where whither whence](https://jansenprice.com/blog/?id=10-Where-Whither-Whence-and-Other-Adverbs)

Comment: +1 "Quo vadis?"